# Using CSS zoom property to modify viewport size from Javascript

Tags: android, ios, css, mobile, media-queries

I'm building mobile site and I would like layout to always fit nicely into mobiles screen available. I know its common to use viewport with device width e.g.:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and then in CSS also use media queries to provide different styles for different resolutions/orientations e.g.:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 460px) and (orientation : portrait)  {
/*styles here*/
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) and (orientation : portrait)  {
/*styles here*/
}
```

et. etc. This can prove quite tedious however if only difference is widths, margins, font sizes etc but the actual layout of elements stay same.Also given the number of screen sizes for different mobiles you will most likely end up with resolutions where your layout dosent fit in perfectly.

Now, I decided to use css `zoom` property that basically zooms in the content. I decided to use simple JS to fit in the content into available screen space automatically:

```
$(".main").css("zoom", $(window).width() / $(".main").width());
```

`.main` is widest element in my webpage, basically container with all the elements inside. So the code above grabs the element and using `zoom` css property resizes it to whatever the available screen size is. From CSS I can still run media queries e.g.:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) and (orientation : portrait)
```

As this use HTML's `meta` tag viewport value that is set to `device-width`, but `zoom` property resizes the content to screen space available nicely.

Now my question is if there is anything wrong with this approach apart from not being pure-css? Is there anything I overlooked?